# MySQL issue.. creating and referencing tables at once

Tags: mysql

I was trying to create multiple tables (some of them referncing the other tables) at once.

I think I matched data types and set primary/foreign keys correctly. But I can only see an error
of 'You cannot add foreign key constraint'. I thought the referenced tables might be created on the first before other tables refernce it, so I reversed the order and the result was the same.

Lastly I tried creating and executing only the referenced tables first(item_type), then referencing tables(item) later.. and... it worked!

However, I wonder if those codes can be executed at once.

Here is code below..
(just two tables are shown to make it simple..)

```
CREATE TABLE item (
    i_id SMALLINT unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    i_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    t_id SMALLINT unsigned NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (i_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (t_id) REFERENCES item_type(t_id)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE item_type (
    t_id SMALLINT unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    t_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(t_id)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't define a foreign key to a table that doesn't exist, so doing the `CREATE TABLE` operations in the order above is not going to work. If you create the `item_type` table first, then the `item` table with the foreign key to `item_type`, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Database engines execute sql code in batches, so one statement that crate table is one batch, but in you example, first batch references second batch which is not executed yet, so change order of batches and it will be working.

```
CREATE TABLE item_type (
    t_id SMALLINT unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    t_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(t_id)
);

CREATE TABLE item (
    i_id SMALLINT unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    i_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    t_id SMALLINT unsigned NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (i_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (t_id) REFERENCES item_type(t_id)
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```